# MySQL: Sequentially number a column based on change in a different column

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

If I have a table with the following columns and values, ordered by `parent_id`:

```
id    parent_id    line_no
--    ---------    -------
1     2            
2     2
3     2
4     3
5     4
6     4
```

And I want to populate `line_no` with a sequential number that starts over at 1 every time the value of `parent_id` changes:

```
id    parent_id    line_no
--    ---------    -------
1     2            1
2     2            2
3     2            3
4     3            1
5     4            1
6     4            2
```

What would the query or sproc look like?

NOTE: I should point out that I only need to do this once. There's a new function in my PHP code that automatically creates the `line_no` every time a new record is added. I just need to update the records that already exist.

Comment: which version of mariadb is being used?

Comment: 10.1.36, but I will also need to do it in a MySQL environment (15.1).

Comment: You wouldn't normally stored (easily) derived data

Comment: We have a specific need for the line number to be stored. Otherwise, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: That's a feature of the `PRIMARY KEY` in `ENGINE=MyISAM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most versions of MySQL do not support `row_number()`.  So, you can do this using variables.  But you have to be very careful.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of variables in the `select`, so a variable should not be assigned an referenced in different expressions.

So:

```
select t.*,
       (@rn := if(@p = parent_id, @rn + 1,
                  if(@p := parent_id, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as line_no
from (select t.* from t order by id) t cross join
     (select @p := 0, @rn := 0) params;
```

The subquery to sort the table may not be necessary.  Somewhere around version 5.7, this became necessary when using variables.

EDIT:

Updating with variables is fun.  In this case, I would just use subqueries with the above:

```
update t join
       (select t.*,
               (@rn := if(@p = parent_id, @rn + 1,
                          if(@p := parent_id, 1, 1)
                         )
               ) as new_line_no
        from (select t.* from t order by id) t cross join
             (select @p := 0, @rn := 0) params
       ) tt
       on t.id = tt.id
    set t.line_no = tt.new_line_no;
```

Comment: I can follow this, but I need to update `line_no` with an actual value. Can this be fashioned into an `UPDATE` statement? Running it as is just returns all rows.

Answer (score 1):

Or, a little more old school...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,parent_id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,    2), 
(2 ,    2), 
(3 ,    2), 
(4 ,    3), 
(5 ,    4), 
(6 ,    4);

SELECT x.*
     , CASE WHEN @prev = parent_id THEN @i := @i+1 ELSE @i := 1 END i
     , @prev := parent_id prev 
  FROM my_table x
     , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
 ORDER 
    BY parent_id,id;
    +----+-----------+------+------+
    | id | parent_id | i    | prev |
    +----+-----------+------+------+
    |  1 |         2 |    1 |    2 |
    |  2 |         2 |    2 |    2 |
    |  3 |         2 |    3 |    2 |
    |  4 |         3 |    1 |    3 |
    |  5 |         4 |    1 |    4 |
    |  6 |         4 |    2 |    4 |
    +----+-----------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery if the `row_number()` doesn't help :

```
select t.*, 
       (select count(*)
        from table t1
        where t1.parent_id = t.parent_id and t1.id <= t.id
       ) as line_no
from table t;
```

Comment: @Chris. . .  I have a `select` statement.